# How to get a cheap nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have some domain names and a hosting package at a certain provider. It is not a very advanced package, so I have no option to create a nameserver there.

I have one domain name that I want to turn into a nameserver for the other domains.

So all my domain names would have ns1.thedomain.com, ns2.thedomain.com, ns3.thedomain.com; thedomain.com would have the same nameservers as well.

I do not want to a rent a whole VPS just for this purpose, nor do I want to use other free services where the nameserver of the primary domain becomes ns2.freedns.eu.com or something like that.

Is there a cheap alternative to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DNS hosting service sounds like what you're after:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service

DynDNS Custom appears to provide just that:

http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/

Side note: They were the only ones that could properly register my .name domain too :)

Comment: If I use dyndns do I still need to have my top domain pointing to ns1.mydyndns.org

Comment: If you wanted to host your own name servers you would setup the registrar with your name server's domain names and IPs then set your domain's your name servers to these. I did this before.

So technically you can create your ns1/2/3 records and point them to any IP address you wish. The issue with this approach is that should those IPs change, your domain names go offline. That's why it's best to use the DynDNS domain names so they can change their IPs if they need to and you don't have to change anything. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok I get your point. I have another question tho. I see that with the basic account I can go upto 10 domain names. So if I only want a nameserver could I just add one domain, and use my nameserver everywhere. Or should I add every domain that usses my nameserver to the account. I have around 3o domain names that I want using my nameserver.

Comment: @Saif Bechan Can you provide a link to what the "basic account" service is please?

Comment: Oh I was looking at the wrong provider, I was looking at http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/enterprisedns/pricing.html. Is this a different kind of service or do they do the same? DynDNS should have a limit aswel right?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have a registered domain name, you can use http://freedns.afraid.org/ to provide free DNS services using your domain name. It worked well for me. There is no need for you to run your own DNS servers, not worth the hassle.

Just make sure your domain name's nameservers point to FreeDNS after you've signed up on their web site. You would change that at the web site of the company that sold you your domain name, the registrar.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?
http://www.wtfdns.com/

Answer (score 2):

Dnsmadeeasy.com is good and really cheap for what they give, not sure if that is in your price range.

Comment: +1 Agreed, for business-grade DNS hosting these guys offer exceptional value for money.

Answer (score 1):

xname.org - free dns, no hassle and no fuss. Works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO [zonedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) its quite good.  Has free entry level service & affordable subscriptions for additional features.
The word free does not appear in the ns so it should be ok for you?